# How to make WS_THICKFRAME invisible, but still functional in MFC?

Tags: c++, mfc

So, I created a dialog that has a style: WS_THICKFRAME.
This WS_THICKFRAME gives the dialog box the functionality to resize the window, but my problems is that I don't won't a border around my window to be visible. How would I make the border invisible, but still have the re-size capability?

An example would be most helpful! Thanks!

Below, are the styles of the template for the dialog box I created:

```
IDD_GADGETTRANSLUCENTDIALOG DIALOGEX 0, 0, 320, 200
STYLE DS_ABSALIGN | DS_SETFONT | DS_MODALFRAME | DS_3DLOOK | DS_FIXEDSYS | WS_SYSMENU | WS_THICKFRAME
```

Comment: Fairly bizarre, how do you expect the user to figure out that clicking an invisible border is going to work?  Use WM_NCHITTEST.

Comment: @Hans Passant The application isn't suppose to have borders, because it is suppose to feel like an gadget that runs in the background. It gives a more intuitive feel what the program is for.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Remove WS_THICKFRAME

Handle WM_NCHITTEST roughly as follows:

```
UINT CMyClass::OnNcHitTest(CPoint point) 
{
   CRect rWindow;
   GetWindowRect(rWindow);

   CRect rInner(rWindow);
   rInner.DeflateRect(GetSystemMetrics(SM_CXBORDER), GetSystemMetrics(SM_CYBORDER));

   if (rWindow.PtInRect(point) && !rInner.PtInRect(point))
   {
      // figure out which of the following codes to return: //
      // HTBOTTOM, HTTOP, HTLEFT, HTRIGHT                   //
      // HTBOTTOMLEFT, HTBOTTOMRIGHT, HTTOPLEFT, HTTOPRIGHT // 
   }
   else
   {
      return CMyBaseClass::OnNcHitTest(point);
   }
}
```