# Create window without titlebar, with resizable border and without bogus 6px white stripe

Tags: winapi, windows-10, paint, gdi

I want a window without title bar but with resizable frames and shadow.
This can easily be achieved by removing WS_CAPTION and adding WS_THICKFRAME, however, since Windows 10, there's a 6px white non-client area.

With the following code I create a window and paint all the client area with black, the window gets a left, right and bottom 6px transparent margins, however the top margin is white.

```
#ifndef UNICODE
#define UNICODE
#endif 

#include <windows.h>

LRESULT CALLBACK WindowProc(HWND hwnd, UINT uMsg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam);

int WINAPI wWinMain(HINSTANCE hInstance, HINSTANCE, PWSTR pCmdLine, int nCmdShow)
{
    // Register the window class.
    const wchar_t CLASS_NAME[]  = L"Sample Window Class";

    WNDCLASS wc = { };

    wc.lpfnWndProc   = WindowProc;
    wc.hInstance     = hInstance;
    wc.lpszClassName = CLASS_NAME;

    RegisterClass(&wc);

    // Create the window.

    HWND hwnd = CreateWindowEx(
        0,                              // Optional window styles.
        CLASS_NAME,                     // Window class
        L"",    // Window text
                0,
        // Size and position
        CW_USEDEFAULT, CW_USEDEFAULT, CW_USEDEFAULT, CW_USEDEFAULT,
        NULL,       // Parent window    
        NULL,       // Menu
        hInstance,  // Instance handle
        NULL        // Additional application data
        );

    ShowWindow(hwnd, nCmdShow);

    LONG lStyle = GetWindowLong(hwnd, GWL_STYLE);
    lStyle |= WS_THICKFRAME;
    lStyle = lStyle & ~WS_CAPTION;
    SetWindowLong(hwnd, GWL_STYLE, lStyle);
    SetWindowPos(hwnd, NULL, 0,0,0,0, SWP_FRAMECHANGED | SWP_NOMOVE | SWP_NOSIZE | SWP_NOZORDER | SWP_NOOWNERZORDER);

    // Run the message loop.

    MSG msg = { };
    while (GetMessage(&msg, NULL, 0, 0))
    {
        TranslateMessage(&msg);
        DispatchMessage(&msg);
    }

    return 0;
}

LRESULT CALLBACK WindowProc(HWND hwnd, UINT uMsg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    switch (uMsg)
    {
    case WM_DESTROY:
        PostQuitMessage(0);
        return 0;

    case WM_PAINT:
        {
            PAINTSTRUCT ps;
            HDC hdc = BeginPaint(hwnd, &ps);


            // Paint everything black
            FillRect(hdc, &ps.rcPaint, (HBRUSH) (COLOR_WINDOWTEXT));
            EndPaint(hwnd, &ps);
        }
        return 0;

    }
    return DefWindowProc(hwnd, uMsg, wParam, lParam);
}
```

Renders:
[image: image showing the problem]

How can I remove the white stripe ?
I also found this related Qt bug report [QTBUG-47543](https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-47543) which was closed as not being a Qt problem, because it can be reproduced with win32 api.

Comment: Check the following solution: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19919147/how-to-make-ws-thickframe-invisible-but-still-functional-in-mfc

Answer (score 15):

That's not a bug. In Windows 10 the borders on left/right/bottom are transparent. The top border is not transparent. You should leave it as is. Probably nobody will complain.

To change it, you must modify the non-client area. This is rather difficult in Windows Vista and above. See [Custom Window Frame Using DWM](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb688195(v=vs.85).aspx) for reference.

- Find border thickness
- Use `DwmExtendFrameIntoClientArea` to get access to non-client area
- Use `BeginBufferedPaint` to draw opaque color over non-client area

Windows 10 example:

[image]

(*See the next example for compatibility with Windows Vista, 7, 8*)

```
//requires Dwmapi.lib and UxTheme.lib
#include <Windows.h>
#include <Dwmapi.h>

void my_paint(HDC hdc, RECT rc)
{
    HBRUSH brush = CreateSolidBrush(RGB(0, 128, 0));
    FillRect(hdc, &rc, brush);
    DeleteObject(brush);
}

LRESULT CALLBACK WindowProc(HWND hwnd, UINT uMsg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    static RECT border_thickness;

    switch (uMsg)
    {
    case WM_CREATE:
    {
        //find border thickness
        SetRectEmpty(&border_thickness);
        if (GetWindowLongPtr(hwnd, GWL_STYLE) & WS_THICKFRAME)
        {
            AdjustWindowRectEx(&border_thickness, GetWindowLongPtr(hwnd, GWL_STYLE) & ~WS_CAPTION, FALSE, NULL);
            border_thickness.left *= -1;
            border_thickness.top *= -1;
        }
        else if (GetWindowLongPtr(hwnd, GWL_STYLE) & WS_BORDER)
        {
            SetRect(&border_thickness, 1, 1, 1, 1);
        }

        MARGINS margins = { 0 };
        DwmExtendFrameIntoClientArea(hwnd, &margins);
        SetWindowPos(hwnd, NULL, 0, 0, 0, 0, SWP_SHOWWINDOW | SWP_NOMOVE | SWP_NOSIZE | SWP_FRAMECHANGED);
        break;
    }

    case WM_PAINT:
    {
        PAINTSTRUCT ps;
        HDC hdc = BeginPaint(hwnd, &ps);

        RECT rc = ps.rcPaint;
        BP_PAINTPARAMS params = { sizeof(params), BPPF_NOCLIP | BPPF_ERASE };
        HDC memdc;
        HPAINTBUFFER hbuffer = BeginBufferedPaint(hdc, &rc, BPBF_TOPDOWNDIB, &params, &memdc);

        my_paint(memdc, rc);

        BufferedPaintSetAlpha(hbuffer, &rc, 255);
        EndBufferedPaint(hbuffer, TRUE);

        EndPaint(hwnd, &ps);
        return 0;
    }

    case WM_NCACTIVATE:
        return 0;

    case WM_NCCALCSIZE:
        if (lParam)
        {
            NCCALCSIZE_PARAMS* sz = (NCCALCSIZE_PARAMS*)lParam;
            sz->rgrc[0].left += border_thickness.left;
            sz->rgrc[0].right -= border_thickness.right;
            sz->rgrc[0].bottom -= border_thickness.bottom;
            return 0;
        }
        break;

    case WM_NCHITTEST:
    {
        //do default processing, but allow resizing from top-border
        LRESULT result = DefWindowProc(hwnd, uMsg, wParam, lParam);
        if (result == HTCLIENT)
        {
            POINT pt = { GET_X_LPARAM(lParam), GET_Y_LPARAM(lParam) };
            ScreenToClient(hwnd, &pt);
            if (pt.y < border_thickness.top) return HTTOP;
        }
        return result;
    }

    case WM_DESTROY:
        PostQuitMessage(0);
        return 0;

    }
    return DefWindowProc(hwnd, uMsg, wParam, lParam);
}

int WINAPI wWinMain(HINSTANCE hInstance, HINSTANCE, PWSTR, int)
{
    const wchar_t CLASS_NAME[] = L"Sample Window Class";

    WNDCLASS wc = {};
    wc.lpfnWndProc = WindowProc;
    wc.hInstance = hInstance;
    wc.hCursor = LoadCursor(NULL, IDC_ARROW);
    wc.lpszClassName = CLASS_NAME;
    RegisterClass(&wc);

    CreateWindowEx(0, CLASS_NAME,   NULL,
        WS_VISIBLE | WS_THICKFRAME | WS_POPUP,
        10, 10, 600, 400, NULL, NULL, hInstance, NULL);

    MSG msg = {};
    while (GetMessage(&msg, NULL, 0, 0))
    {
        TranslateMessage(&msg);
        DispatchMessage(&msg);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

For compatibility with Windows Vista/7/8 use this procedure instead. This will paint over left/top/bottom borders as well as top border. This window will appear as a simple rectangle, with resizing borders:

[image]

```
//for Windows Vista, 7, 8, 10
LRESULT CALLBACK WindowProc(HWND hwnd, UINT uMsg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    static RECT border_thickness;

    switch (uMsg)
    {
    case WM_CREATE:
    {
        //find border thickness
        SetRectEmpty(&border_thickness);
        if (GetWindowLongPtr(hwnd, GWL_STYLE) & WS_THICKFRAME)
        {
            AdjustWindowRectEx(&border_thickness, GetWindowLongPtr(hwnd, GWL_STYLE) & ~WS_CAPTION, FALSE, NULL);
            border_thickness.left *= -1;
            border_thickness.top *= -1;
        }
        else if (GetWindowLongPtr(hwnd, GWL_STYLE) & WS_BORDER)
        {
            SetRect(&border_thickness, 1, 1, 1, 1);
        }

        MARGINS margins = { 0 };
        DwmExtendFrameIntoClientArea(hwnd, &margins);
        SetWindowPos(hwnd, NULL, 0, 0, 0, 0, SWP_SHOWWINDOW | SWP_NOMOVE | SWP_NOSIZE | SWP_FRAMECHANGED);
        break;
    }

    case WM_PAINT:
    {
        PAINTSTRUCT ps;
        HDC hdc = BeginPaint(hwnd, &ps);

        RECT rc = ps.rcPaint;
        BP_PAINTPARAMS params = { sizeof(params), BPPF_NOCLIP | BPPF_ERASE };
        HDC memdc;
        HPAINTBUFFER hbuffer = BeginBufferedPaint(hdc, &rc, BPBF_TOPDOWNDIB, &params, &memdc);

        my_paint(memdc, rc);

        BufferedPaintSetAlpha(hbuffer, &rc, 255);
        EndBufferedPaint(hbuffer, TRUE);

        EndPaint(hwnd, &ps);
        return 0;
    }

    case WM_NCACTIVATE:
        return 0;

    case WM_NCCALCSIZE:
        if (lParam)
            return 0;

    case WM_NCHITTEST:
    {
        POINT pt = { GET_X_LPARAM(lParam), GET_Y_LPARAM(lParam) };
        ScreenToClient(hwnd, &pt);
        RECT rc;
        GetClientRect(hwnd, &rc);
        enum {left=1, top=2, right=4, bottom=8};
        int hit = 0;
        if (pt.x < border_thickness.left) hit |= left;
        if (pt.x > rc.right - border_thickness.right) hit |= right;
        if (pt.y < border_thickness.top) hit |= top;
        if (pt.y > rc.bottom - border_thickness.bottom) hit |= bottom;

        if (hit & top && hit & left) return HTTOPLEFT;
        if (hit & top && hit & right) return HTTOPRIGHT;
        if (hit & bottom && hit & left) return HTBOTTOMLEFT;
        if (hit & bottom && hit & right) return HTBOTTOMRIGHT;
        if (hit & left) return HTLEFT;
        if (hit & top) return HTTOP;
        if (hit & right) return HTRIGHT;
        if (hit & bottom) return HTBOTTOM;

        return HTCLIENT;
    }

    case WM_DESTROY:
        PostQuitMessage(0);
        return 0;

    }
    return DefWindowProc(hwnd, uMsg, wParam, lParam);
}
```

Comment: Your Win7 compat example doesn't have shadow around frame, any way to get one ?

Comment: You can add `wc.style = CS_DROPSHADOW;` for `WNDCLASS` registration. This drops shadow for right side and bottom side. To add shadows all around it has to be done manually, with GDI+ for example.

Comment: Sometimes I still see the white stripe. Catching WM_NCACTIVATE fixes most of the occurrances, but sometimes when moving the window really fast it gets the white stripe. Any other Windows event I should block ?

Comment: @BarmakShemirani it removes the white resize border on top and also resizability of window! I want to be able to resize the window. I am using Win 10. What I am doing wrong? I am exactly using your code

Comment: @Reza you probably didn't add `WS_THICKFRAME` style for your window

Answer (score 4):

Just to expand on this a little; in order to remove the white stripe one just has to remove the corresponding value from the first rect in NCCALCSIZE. pywin32 code would be:

```
    if msg == WM_NCCALCSIZE:
        if wParam:
            res = CallWindowProc(
                wndProc, hWnd, msg, wParam, lParam
            )
            sz = NCCALCSIZE_PARAMS.from_address(lParam)
            sz.rgrc[0].top -= 6 # remove 6px top border!
            return res
```

Comment: It seems to me that it is better to use not the constant "6", but the result of a function call AdjustWindowRectEx(&border_thickness, GetWindowLongPtr(hwnd, GWL_STYLE) & ~WS_CAPTION, FALSE, NULL); and then get border_thickness.top

Answer (score 2):

I think we don't need to work with DWM to remove this border. This white top resize border belongs to the non-client area of a window. So for removing it you should handle window messages related to the resizing and activating of non-client area of a window like below: ( tested only on Win 10 )

```
  LRESULT CALLBACK WindowProc(HWND hWnd, UINT uMsg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
  {
    /* When we have a custom titlebar in the window, we don't need the non-client area of a normal window
      * to be painted. In order to achieve this, we handle the "WM_NCCALCSIZE" which is responsible for the
      * size of non-client area of a window and set the return value to 0. Also we have to tell the
      * application to not paint this area on activate and deactivation events so we also handle
      * "WM_NCACTIVATE" message. */
      switch( nMsg )
      {
      case WM_NCACTIVATE:
      {
        /* Returning 0 from this message disable the window from receiving activate events which is not
        desirable. However When a visual style is not active (?) for this window, "lParam" is a handle to an
        optional update region for the nonclient area of the window. If this parameter is set to -1,
        DefWindowProc does not repaint the nonclient area to reflect the state change. */
        lParam = -1;
        break;
      }
      /* To remove the standard window frame, you must handle the WM_NCCALCSIZE message, specifically when
      its wParam value is TRUE and the return value is 0 */
      case WM_NCCALCSIZE:
        if( wParam )
        {
          /* Detect whether window is maximized or not. We don't need to change the resize border when win is
          *  maximized because all resize borders are gone automatically */
          WINDOWPLACEMENT wPos;
          // GetWindowPlacement fail if this member is not set correctly.
          wPos.length = sizeof( wPos );
          GetWindowPlacement( hWnd, &wPos );
          if( wPos.showCmd != SW_SHOWMAXIMIZED )
          {
            RECT borderThickness;
            SetRectEmpty( &borderThickness );
            AdjustWindowRectEx( &borderThickness,
              GetWindowLongPtr( hWnd, GWL_STYLE ) & ~WS_CAPTION, FALSE, NULL );
            borderThickness.left *= -1;
            borderThickness.top *= -1;
            NCCALCSIZE_PARAMS* sz = reinterpret_cast< NCCALCSIZE_PARAMS* >( lParam );
            // Add 1 pixel to the top border to make the window resizable from the top border
            sz->rgrc[ 0 ].top += 1;
            sz->rgrc[ 0 ].left += borderThickness.left;
            sz->rgrc[ 0 ].right -= borderThickness.right;
            sz->rgrc[ 0 ].bottom -= borderThickness.bottom;
            return 0;
          }
        }
        break;
      }
    return DefWindowProc(hWnd, uMsg, wParam, lParam);
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
case WM_NCCALCSIZE: {
    // This must always be last.
    NCCALCSIZE_PARAMS* sz = reinterpret_cast<NCCALCSIZE_PARAMS*>(lparam);

    // Add 8 pixel to the top border when maximized so the app isn't cut off

        // on windows 10, if set to 0, there's a white line at the top
        // of the app and I've yet to find a way to remove that.
    sz->rgrc[0].top += 1;
    sz->rgrc[0].right -= 8;
    sz->rgrc[0].bottom -= 8;
    sz->rgrc[0].left -= -8;
     
    // Previously (WVR_HREDRAW | WVR_VREDRAW), but returning 0 or 1 doesn't
    // actually break anything so I've set it to 0. Unless someone pointed a
    // problem in the future.
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on @blameless75 solution for WinUi3

I use [Microsoft.Windows.CsWin32](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Windows.CsWin32) to generate PInvoke methods.

NativeMethods.txt

```
NCCALCSIZE_PARAMS
AdjustWindowRectEx
GetWindowLongPtr
SetLastError
SetWindowLong
SetWindowLongPtr
```

Win32Helper method

```
public static IntPtr SetWindowLong(IntPtr hWnd, WINDOW_LONG_PTR_INDEX nIndex, IntPtr dwNewLong)
{
    int error = 0;
    IntPtr result = IntPtr.Zero;
    // Win32 SetWindowLong doesn't clear error on success
    PInvoke.SetLastError(0);

#if x86
    int tempResult = PInvoke.SetWindowLong((Windows.Win32.Foundation.HWND)hWnd, nIndex, IntPtrToInt32(dwNewLong));
    error = Marshal.GetLastWin32Error();
    result = new IntPtr(tempResult);
#endif

#if x64 || ARM64

    result = PInvoke.SetWindowLongPtr((Windows.Win32.Foundation.HWND)hWnd, nIndex, dwNewLong);
    error = Marshal.GetLastWin32Error();
#endif
    if (result == IntPtr.Zero && error != 0)
    {
        throw new System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception(error);
    }
```

Window

```
using Microsoft.UI.Xaml;
using System;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using Windows.Win32;
using Windows.Win32.Foundation;
using Windows.Win32.UI.WindowsAndMessaging;

namespace Demo
{
    public class PopupWindow : Window
    {
        private const int WM_NCCALCSIZE = 0x0083;
        
        private IntPtr setWindowLongWndProc;
        private WNDPROC wndProc;
        RECT rect = new RECT();
        public PopupWindow(): base()
        {
            var hWndMain = WinRT.Interop.WindowNative.GetWindowHandle(this);
            var style = (WINDOW_STYLE)PInvoke.GetWindowLongPtr(new HWND(hWndMain), WINDOW_LONG_PTR_INDEX.GWL_STYLE);            
            PInvoke.AdjustWindowRectEx(ref rect, style & ~WINDOW_STYLE.WS_CAPTION, false, 0);

            wndProc = WNDPROC;
            setWindowLongWndProc = Win32Helper.SetWindowLong(hWndMain, WINDOW_LONG_PTR_INDEX.GWL_WNDPROC, Marshal.GetFunctionPointerForDelegate(wndProc));            
            // hide title bar or create own here
        }

        private LRESULT WNDPROC(HWND param0, uint paraml, WPARAM param2, LPARAM param3)
        {
            switch (paraml)
            {
                case WM_NCCALCSIZE:
                    if (param2.Value == 1)
                    {
                        var structure = Marshal.PtrToStructure<NCCALCSIZE_PARAMS>(param3);                        
                        structure.rgrc._0.top += rect.top;
                        Marshal.StructureToPtr(structure, param3, false);
                    }                                    
                    break;
            }

            return PInvoke.CallWindowProc((WNDPROC)Marshal.GetDelegateForFunctionPointer(setWindowLongWndProc, typeof(WNDPROC)), param0, paraml, param2, param3);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Change the style of dialog.

```
LONG lStyle = GetWindowLong(hwnd, GWL_STYLE);
lStyle |= WS_THICKFRAME; // 6px white stripe cause of this.
lStyle = lStyle & ~WS_CAPTION;
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.[Read this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: You just copied 3 lines of code from my original post.
Can you show the code that will actually fix it ?

Comment: @SergioMartins remove WS_THCIFRAME property.

Comment: That makes the window non resizable, but the question was to keep the window resizable

Comment: While this removes the annoying horizontal border just from the top of the window, you're still unable to resize the window manually.