# WPF Custom MainWindow using CreateWindowEx()

Tags: c#, wpf, windows, winapi

I was working on a project using WPF, I want to modify the `MainWindow` to have some extended window styles. I have referred some docs and found out that I can set the window styles using `SetWindowLong()`, but in my case it will not work because I am trying to use `WS_EX_NOREDIRECTIONBITMAP` as the extended window style. when I use `SetWindowLong()` it does nothing. I have read somewhere that `WS_EX_NOREDIRECTIONBITMAP` can only be set while creating the window. So is there any way that i could modify the `CreateWindowEx()` of the WPF `MainWindow`.

I have found another alternate method to achieve this but it is by using the Undocumented API function.(`SetWindowCompositionAttribute()`). I need my project to be stable so is there any other method to achieve this?

If `SetWindowCompositionAttribute()` can set `WS_EX_NOREDIRECTIONBITMAP` at runtime, there must be a workaround to do this.

Here is the screenshot of what i want to achieve :

[image: Sample Image]

It is possible to do it in C++ but in C# WPF i haven't found a way to do this.

Comment: You can't use an existing "managed" desktop 15-years old UI frameworks such as Winforms or WPF and do your own low-level stuff with it. Either you use them because they're relatively easy to program (and suffer their true lack of modernity with regards with today's Windows technologies, ie: Direct Composition or Windows.UI.Composition, DirectX, etc) or go and write your own Win32 desktop stuff where you have access to everything. In theory, WinUI3 (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/apps/winui/winui3/) will fill the gap, but it's not there yet and details are uncertain.

Comment: What specifically would you want the window to do/look like after changing it?

Comment: @o_w There's only one reason why you would want to use the `WS_EX_NOREDIRECTIONBITMAP` window style: It prevents the system from allocating a redirection bitmap for cases where you don't need it. [This Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/q/49380566/1889329) provides more information.

Comment: Using WS_EX_NOREDIRECTIONBITMAP will create a window without loosing it's shadow. since the WPF uses DirectX to render controls the redirection surface is not required. i have tried it. the WPF was able to draw to a window with WS_EX_NOREDIRECTIONBITMAP (i used undocumented api). the DWMExtendFrameIntoClient Area will produce a black border if i set all the margins below 11 so if i use WS_EX_NOREDIRECTIONBITMAP this problem is solved and that's why i need it

Comment: and i don't know why everyone is down voting, i have explained as much as i can. I was not able to add any codes because i don't know what I will add there. all i just want to do is a blank wpf window with WS_EX_NOREDIRECTIONBITMAP.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to set `WS_EX_NOREDIRECTIONBITMAP` during creating `MainWindow` then you can create `MainWindow` manually. Just remove `StartupUri` from App.xaml and create new event handler for `Startup` event.

```
<Application x:Class="WpfApp1.App"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         Startup="App_Startup">
```

App.xaml.cs

```
void App_Startup(object sender, StartupEventArgs e)
{
    // replace with your code
    MainWindow window = new MainWindow();
    window.Show();
}
```

But it would be useful if you can shore more code.

Comment: But can you please tell me how will i set it