# Win32 API - how to access mouse events with layered transparent window WNDPROC or hook?

Tags: winapi, rust

I have a window which serves as an overlay, and only has some part of it non-transparent. The window has extended styles

```rust
WS_EX_TOOLWINDOW | WS_EX_TOPMOST | WS_EX_TRANSPARENT | WS_EX_LAYERED
```

And the transparency is set with:

```rust
SetLayeredWindowAttributes(hwnd, RGB(255, 255, 255), 0, LWA_COLORKEY);
```

I do want to read the mouse events to implement the interactive part of the overlay.

So far i tried catching messages like

```rust
WM_MOUSEMOVE,
WM_KEYDOWN,
WM_NCLBUTTONDOWN,
```

in my WNDPROC and there they didn't fire. I assumed that was due to some of the window extended styles, and by removing one at a time i found out that it was layered window attribute which caused it. Sadly my app does depend on this attribute for its transparency.

Then i tried registering a windows hook for that very process and thread to intercept the mouse events. I don't know the internals of hooks at all - but i thought they get access to the messages before they enter the application's queue hence i hoped i could read them before whatever interferes passes them on. That didn't work sadly.
I registered the hook like so:

```rust
app_state.hhook = SetWindowsHookExW(WH_MOUSE,
                                    Some(Self::HOOKPROC),
                                    GetModuleHandleW(null_mut()),
                                    GetCurrentThreadId();
```

And the actual HOOKPROC was defined like this:

```rust
pub unsafe extern "system" fn HOOKPROC(ncode: c_int, wparam: WPARAM, lparam: LPARAM) -> LRESULT {
    println!("fired!");
    CallNextHookEx(null_mut(), ncode, wparam, lparam)
}
```

Sadly this didn't output anything to STDOUT, but I do think that hook was registered as unhook function didn't return 0.

My next idea was to put the hook in the process which manages the previous window. However the below doesn't work.

```rust
app_state.hhook = SetWindowsHookExW(WH_MOUSE,
                                    Some(Self::HOOKPROC),
                                    GetModuleHandleW(null_mut()),
                                    GetWindowThreadProcessId(
                                    GetWindow(hwnd, GW_HWNDPREV), null_mut())
                                    );
```

I think that it's due to the fact that i need to place the hook in a separate dll but event if it does work - this solution seem to be very dirty and will probably work in very few cases without requiring elevated privileges. What can i do to achieve the desired via accepted and cohesive code?

Comment: Do you want the entire window to receive mouse input?

Comment: @IInspectable I can deal with that, but the ideal scenario would be only the non zero alpha part and the rest pass through.

Comment: Keeping an entire window opaque to mouse input, but allowing it to display any content is outlined in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49380666/1889329).

Comment: @IInspectable the issue is i do want to get mouse input, but only in the non transparent area of the window - or (to hell with it) just get access to all the mouse messages without taking them out of the queue so underlying windows can use them. And i sadly don't see how that link is relevant. (Could you explain where exactly should i look)

Comment: @RemyLebeau that's hilarious - i just found that after 6 hrs now by accidentally hovering mouse over the opaque part :). Could you post this as answer so i can accept it?

Comment: That was written in response to *"I can deal with that"*. I doubted that you could. There is no way for your window to let mouse input fall through to a window underneath it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just get rid of the `WS_EX_TRANSPARENT` style and use `WS_EX_LAYERED` by itself, and let the OS handle mouse input normally (no hook needed). Fully transparent pixels will fall-through as expected, and the window will receive input messages on non-transparent pixels.