# JavaFX add custom button to the title Stage

Tags: java, javafx

How can I add a custom button to the title Stage with JavaFX, in this case a "help" button? I'm using Linux.

[image]

Comment: You can't customize the title bar of a decorated window using the standard JavaFX API.

Comment: If you're willing to put in the work and try to access native code, then it may be possible to do this via JNI or JNA (or maybe even the currently-incubating _Foreign Function and Memory API_). [This Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75533171/how-does-javafx-integrate-the-title-bar-and-menu-bar) seems to show at least the beginnings of customizing the title bar on Windows.

Comment: You could create *another* undecorated stage and, listening to the stage x and y and width properties, set the x and y of the undecorated stage (making the undecorated stage non-modal and owned by the main stage).  It might work (I didn't try), it is a hacky solution and won't work quite right if the OS defaulted decorated layout isn't exactly as you expected to be (that layout will change depending on the OS version or Linux window manager theme used).

Comment: My suggestion is to abandon your idea to put a help icon in the title bar.  Instead, put the help icon in the main window (look at your StackOverflow window and see where the help question mark is located on the top right - something like that).

Comment: Thanks a lot. It is a pity that there are no standard tools

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Preface:**

You can't modify the title bar of Stages in JavaFX.

**Workaround solution:**

Build your own title bar, add it to top of your Scene, and remove the original title bar.

1. Use `BorderPane` as root node of your `Scene`.
2. Create your title bar in the "top" Part of the `BorderPane`.
3. Remove the original `Stage` title bar with `stage.initStyle(StageStyle.UNDECORATED);`.

Comment: Of course, it’s a little harder than that.  (I assume you meant BorderPane, not BorderLayout, by the way.)  Simulating a menu bar requires adding the application icon, title (using the platform’s title bar font), and minimize/maximize/close buttons (ideally using the platform’s own icons).  And changing appearance based on whether the window is focused.  And supporting window dragging, title bar double-clicking, and simulating the system’s context menu for window title bars.  All doable, but not a trivial effort.

Comment: Thank you because Layout!=Pane! Yes, you are right. Everything must be created by hand. Close, maximize, minimize is not hard, but dragging will require some effort.

Comment: See also [_JavaFX entirely customized windows?_](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12874664/230513)